# How To LongPool in Node.js and Javascript without not making alot of network request

Tags: node.js, long-polling

I make a Longpolling for this little project but alot of Network Request are been sent and later ther browser froze
.

Is there anything that i am doing wrong here

*On the server side*

**server.js**
`

```js
//...

const PORT = 3000;
let subscribers = Object.create(null);

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
  const urlPath = parsedUrl.pathname;
  const queryStringObject = parsedUrl.query;
  const method = req.method.toLowerCase();

  if (urlPath === "/" && method === "get") {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    });

    res.end(`<h1>Home Page of the API</h1>`);

    return;
  }

  if (urlPath === "/datas" && method === "get") {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache, must-revalidate",
    });

    let id = Math.random();

    subscribers[id] = res;

    fs.readFile(`${process.cwd()}/data/datas.json`, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
      res.end(data);
    });

    req.on("close", function () {
      delete subscribers[id];
      // console.log(`${id} deleted`);
    });

    return;
  }
});

server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  console.log(`Server up and running,\nYou can now visit http://localhost:3000`);
});
```

`

*and on the client Side*

**app.js**

`

```js
const prices = document.querySelector(".prices");

function createEl(resultDatas) {
  prices.innerHTML = "";

  resultDatas.forEach((resultData) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("element-container");

    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = resultData.title;
    if (resultData.title.toLowerCase() === "silver") {
      p.classList.add(`silver`);
    }
    p.classList.add(`title`);
    div.appendChild(p);

    const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.innerHTML = resultData.price;
    h3.classList.add("price");
    div.appendChild(h3);

    prices.append(div);
  });
}

let tickerData = null;

const fetchTickerValue = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/datas");
    const data = await response.json();
    createEl(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error?.message ?? "ticker call failed");
  } finally {
    fetchTickerValue();
  }
};

fetchTickerValue();

if (tickerData) console.log(tickerData);
```

`

I want only one request to be send while waiting for the response from the server

[image]

[image]